# [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]

Tags: laravel-5

I am not able to seed the db and having this error.   [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
Class 'Channel' not found

This is for laravel 5.3 running mysql.

```
 function run()
    {
        $channel1=['title'=>'Laravel'];
        $channel2=['title'=>'Css3'];
        $channel3=['title'=>'Vue.Js'];
        $channel4=['title'=>'CakePhp'];
        $channel5=['title'=>'Node.js'];
        $channel6=['title'=>'Javascript'];

        Channel::create($channel1);
        Channel::create($channel2);
        Channel::create($channel3);
        Channel::create($channel4);
        Channel::create($channel5);
        Channel::create($channel6);
   }



I am expecting to seed the db
```

Comment: Di did you import the class Channel? use App\Channel

Comment: in where? config/app.php?